# Find duplicates in single and n-dimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some arrays, for example:

```
a = [1, 2];
b = [2];
```

and

```
a = [1, [2], [[3]]];
b = [[2], [[3]]];
```

How I can return duplicate values from single and n-dimensional arrays?
Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: You might find [Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) helpful with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Intrigued by the idea of returning just dupes, I toyed with this function. It uses [array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to press everything into a single 1D array, then uses [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return only the duplicates.

```js
const returnDupes = (arr1, arr2) => {
let arr = arr1.concat(arr2).flat(5);
return arr.reduce((acc, n) => {
  if (arr.filter(a => a === n).length > 1 && acc.indexOf(n)===-1) acc.push(n)
  return acc;
}, [])
}

let a = [1, [2], [[3]]], b = [[2], [[3]]];
console.log(returnDupes(a,b))

a = [1, 2]
b = [2];
console.log(returnDupes(a,b))
```